# Distributing iOS 5 Applications

Tags: ios, ios5

is it okay already to build and distribute apps for iOS 5? because weeks before i have heard it is still not; or maybe, can I find that in the developer site of apple that it's okay already to build iOS 5 Applications? (maybe some kind of Announcement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is ok. Apple started accepting them weeks ago. Since October 4th, I believe:

http://www.macstories.net/news/apple-to-developers-submit-your-ios-5-apps/

Comment: for as long as it's not beta? that's just the requirement right?

Comment: You have to use the official 4.2 tools, no beta tools. It will fail to upload if you don't use the right tools, so no worries really. Just update via App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I received a notification email from Apple/iTunesConnect that I could start uploading iOS 5 apps.

Comment: so you'll be notified also with your account, I see, thanks :D

Comment: Well, it seemed to be a general email rather than just to me. Maybe it only went to folks with apps already in the store, or who have accepted the contract [shrug]. Anyone should be able to submit iOS5.